# How to call to parent constructor of generic class

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have a class *A* and a class *B* which extends *A*

```
public class A<T1, T2> {

    private T1 x;
    private T2 y;

    public A(T1 x, T2 y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

The above code works fine, now for class B

```
public class B<T1,T2,T3> extends A {
    private T3 z;

    public Triplet(T1 x, T2 y, T3 z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Eclipse gives the following warning on this code:

**Type safety: The constructor A(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type A. References to generic type A should be parameterized**

What does this mean, is my super call incorrect or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to specify your parent class generics

```
public class B<T1,T2,T3> extends A<T1,T2> {
```

Comment: It would have been obvious if the notion of my wrong reference to generic type A would have been on the location of the reference. Namely in the class declaration